# Connecting two lans over internet with Microsoft Ras

Tags: windows-server-2003, rras

I have the following structure

20 computers in city 1 with lan 192.168.0.1/24
15 computers in city 2 with lan 192.168.1.1/24

both connected to the internet with ADSL modems (ADSL Modem with ip 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1), both have a DHCP server

in city 1 I have a Windows 2003 server with Remote Access Service (RRAS).
in city 2 I have another windows 2003 server.

How can I make the computers of city 1 ping and use a network printer of city 2 computer and vice versa

Comment: You set up a site-to-site VPN.  But, frankly, since Server 2003 goes EoL in 5 months (July 14th), I wouldn't bother setting up anything new on Server 2003.  Upgrade your servers, and while you're at it. maybe get a proper router at each site to setup a site-to-site VPN on... or at the very least, a server OS with a newer version of RRAS.

Comment: My company will not pay for new server license, so I need to do this with what I already have

Comment: Well, good luck with that, and hopefully someone who can help you out will come along and do so, but one of the consequences of using software that's end of life, or nearly end of life, is that it gets increasingly difficult to get any help with it.  Now, not to get into your business, and at the risk of giving you career advice... but a company that won't even spend a few hundred bucks on a site-to-site VPN is probably not a company you want to work at, especially when you're in IT.  So, something to think about.